# How to restrict code access in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to restrict code access for the code inside SSRS reports. For example, I can add the following VB.Net code to a Textbox in an SSRS report and have it read in the contents of a file:

```
=System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.xml")
```

Our customers are allowed to provide their own reports that will run on our servers so this kind of access cannot be allowed.

SSRS 2014 and before use .Net 2.0 to run the code in the reports and say you should configure this through Code Access Security. Code Access Security is "legacy" in .Net 4 and does not exist in .Net Core but still alive and kicking in .Net 2.0!

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of but cannot get it to stop allowing the report code to freely read files. Specifically I have added the named permission set:

```
<PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="MyPermissionSet" Description="REMOVE ME!!!">
    <IPermission class="FileIOPermission" version="1" />
</PermissionSet>
```

And then I updated the `Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions` to use the above permission set:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" version="1" PermissionSetName="MyPermissionSet" Name="Report_Expressions_Default_Permissions" Description="This code group grants default permissions for code in report expressions and Code element. ">
          <IMembershipCondition class="StrongNameMembershipCondition" version="1" PublicKeyBlob="..." />
```

I feel that I'm doing something stupid but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Seems like the best option would be to restrict this at the Service Account level: set the SSRS service account to be a Domain account with minimal permissions. IIRC this account won't need much, and will get the needed permissions when it is added to the Report Server group: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160340.aspx

Comment: The problem is we want to control a bunch of other obvious stuff like not allowing the code to use reflection, etc. Those things can't be controlled by a Service Account but can be by Code Access Security. I should have mentioned that in my question. Also I want to lock out all file access and the SSRS Server needs some access to run.